# postgresql 9.3 log slow queries

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, rails-postgresql

I am using Rails application with Postgres 9.3 database and doing some performance fixes. I would like to know how to find out slowest queries in log files. let say queries taking more then 30ms.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-MIN-DURATION-STATEMENT

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In postgresql.conf you should uncomment line

```
#log_min_duration_statement = -1
```

and change its value to 30. This way queries longer than 30ms will be logged