# How to tune my Postgres server?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a 4 GB server with 80GB hard disk. The website is really slow when switching between pages. I checked top processes and postgres processes with 70 -100 % cpu usage keep popping up. they dont last for more than 4 seconds usually and then its a new one. In my postgres database table i have about 12 tables but one of them has about 90 million entries( rows). This is the table causing the slowdown. But how do i tune my postgres parameters like shared_buffer size and all for optimum performance?

It runs on Ubuntu 16 OS, its a django webapp.

my database name is roctim it has size 15 gigabites (as of now, but is increasing)

```
postgres=# select datname, pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size(oid)) as db_size from pg_database;

  datname  | db_size
-----------+---------
 template1 | 6857 kB
 template0 | 6857 kB
 postgres  | 6992 kB
 roctim    | 15 GB
```

the size of my biggest table is 15 GB called "Webapp_sensordata". It collects and stores livedata from machines like crushers, conveyors etc.

When I run `select query from pg_stat_statements order by total_time desc;`,
I get

```
SELECT "Webapp_sensordata"."id", "Webapp_sensordata"."timestamp",
       "Webapp_sensordata"."value", "Webapp_sensordata"."machine_id",
       "Webapp_sensordata"."type_id"
FROM "Webapp_sensordata"
WHERE "Webapp_sensordata"."machine_id" = ?
ORDER BY "Webapp_sensordata"."timestamp" DESC
LIMIT ?
```

and

```
SELECT "Webapp_sensordata"."id", "Webapp_sensordata"."timestamp",
       "Webapp_sensordata"."value", "Webapp_sensordata"."machine_id",
       "Webapp_sensordata"."type_id"
FROM "Webapp_sensordata"
WHERE ("Webapp_sensordata"."type_id" = ?
  AND "Webapp_sensordata"."machine_id" = ?)
ORDER BY "Webapp_sensordata"."timestamp" DESC
LIMIT ?
```

as the top two queries, they both access the big table sensor data.

Also my shared_buffer and working_mem is set to the default right now (128mb and 4mb)

When I ran EXPLAIN ANALYZE the second query shown above, i got

```
QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
----------------------
Sort  (cost=62127.86..62135.64 rows=3111 width=24) (actual 
time=781.051..781.230 rows=2860 loops=1)
Sort Key: "timestamp" DESC
Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 320kB
->  Index Scan using "Webapp_sensordata_machine_id_e353fc5a" on 
"Webapp_sensordata"  (cost=0.57..61947.37 rows=3111 width=24) (actual 
time=4.190..779.783 rows=2860 loops=1)
     Index Cond: (machine_id = 3)
     Filter: (type_id = 1)
     Rows Removed by Filter: 31440
Planning time: 4.572 ms
Execution time: 781.449 ms
(9 rows)
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions. Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I tried my best to explain with all the details i have. I'm not a database expert, if the answer needs more information im glad to post it as soon as i know what more is needed

Comment: Well, to help you people need to know more - which OS you have? Add size of your database - using for example `select datname, pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size(oid)) as db_size from pg_database`. Add size of your biggest table - using for example `select ns.nspname, c.relname, pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(c.oid)) as table_size from pg_class c join pg_namespace ns on c.relnamespace=ns.oid where relkind='r' order by table_size desc`.

Comment: You need to find the slow statements, run `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` on them and add the result to the question.

Comment: @JosMac I've added the results from your queries.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe how do i find the slow statements?

Comment: Good, thanks. So with table of size 15 GB and 4 GB RAM you do not have much chance to cash it in memory. As for logging queries - check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41746897/postgresql-9-3-log-slow-queries - set it to the reasonable value. Once you catch queries which are slowest please add explain plan as mentioned by @LaurenzAlbe plus please add how you set "shared_buffers" and "work_mem"

Comment: @user6714507 You find the slow statements with `pg_stat_statements`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I added my slow statements to the questions

Comment: @JosMac I've added my current settings to question

Comment: Ok, then run `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` on the queries and tune them.

Comment: Also ensure that columns being used in JOIN or WHERE clauses are indexed, and that the table is VACUUMed at an appropriate rate.

Comment: Please share the table structure for `Webapp_sensordata`. Along with all indexes that are defined. Two strategies that would help with the execution of these queries. (1) Having Indexes on the fields `type_id` & `machine_id`. (2) horizontal partitioning of the table, which you can read more [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/ddl-partitioning.html), and [constraint exclusion](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/runtime-config-query.html#GUC-CONSTRAINT-EXCLUSION)

Comment: @user6714507 what is the data type of "type_id" ? my curiosity

Comment: Please add output of `EXPLAIN ...` as mentioned above with current setting of work_mem. After that please try in same connection (aka the same pgAdmin or other GUI window) to run first `set work_mem='16MB';` and after it `EXPLAIN ...` again and look if you will see differences in costs, sorts etc. You can try higher values like 32MB or 64MB or 128MB but here you have to be careful - usable value depends on how many connections you usually have. Work_mem can influence explain plan very significantly...

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe When i ran explain on the second query i got this
                                                                QUERY PLAN
 Limit  (cost=0.57..1339.55 rows=1 width=24)
   ->  Index Scan Backward using "Webapp_sensordata_timestamp_7413cb56" on "Webapp_sensordata"  (cost=0.57..4158886.21 rows=3106 width=24)
         Filter: ((type_id = 1) AND (machine_id = 3))
(3 rows)

Comment: I feel a bit iffy on tuning issue. As an orthodox dbms user, what i believe is "autotune beats manual". So i'll leave some advice on sql query at comments sections and hope you best. If you want to order by a timestamp on a 15GB table https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90277/timestamp-based-index for cluster index. And play with data type of "type_id" ,changes may not take effect right away so a copy of the table created with different "type_id" and trying out those will show improvements immediately

Comment: @user6714507 That's plain EXPLAIN without ANALYZE, so not really useful. And please add it to the question.

Comment: @user2102266 type_id is a foreign key of another model data_type which contains (id, unit, content_identifier) where content_identifier is a foreign key of a model with ( id(int) , string)

Comment: @user6714507 did you try the cluster index?

Comment: @user2102266 the timestamp field in sensordata table is already indexed, it was set db_index=true when adding the field to the django model. I'm not sure if its a clustered index

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I added results from  analyze

Comment: Idk if django will do that. SHOW INDEX FROM "Webapp_sensordata" if timestamp is in the list, sorting is tuned as @LaurenzAlbe mentioned in answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your query would be faster if both conditions and the sort can be handled during the index scan by a multi-column index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON "Webapp_sensordata" (type_id, machine_id, timestamp);
```

Comment: Should "timestamp" also be indexed since it has a order by on it ?

Comment: Oh, absolutely. Thanks for mentioning it.